# global exception handling for rest exposed spring-data

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

Using spring-data-rest to expose repositories i want to overwrite the default exception handling.

reading documentation it looks to me that the best wat would be using a @ControllerAdvice annotated class

```
@ControllerAdvice
class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalControllerExceptionHandler.class);

    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> badRequest(HttpServletRequest req, Exception exception) {
        log.info("++++ GLOBAL EXCEPTION HANDLING ++++");
        return null;
    }
}
```

There are several point i am not sure about:

- Should i extend ResponseEntityExceptionHandler, other class, nothing?
- Should i return ResponseEntity object, other class?

By the way this does not seems to work even when i've tried different configurations. Is there a way to customize error handling in spring-data-rest?

Comment: what do you mean by "this does not seem to work"? Is badRequest not being invoked when an exception is thrown, or are you getting some error?

Comment: Sorry ... i mean badRequest is not being invoked

Comment: Are you using @EnableAutoConfiguration? It'd be helpful to see the main configuration. Also curious if this class is in the same package as that configuration, since this class is package-private.

Comment: This class is in a subpackage of the Application since i expect the spring context to scan all these subpackages ... am i wrong? ... BTW yes, i am using EnableAutoConfiguration

Comment: it will component scan the package, but it won't be visible to the component scan; in java, either you are in the same package or you are not-- there really is no such thing as a "subpackage" from the standpoint of accessibility

Comment: mmm ... maybe i am wrong but i think Spring has the concept of subpackage when dealing with component auto scanning. In the Spring XML notation you can declare <context:component-scan base-package="com.example"> then that base-package will be considerer as root and  subpackages will be scanned as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74123/discussion-between-gyoder-and-rafael).

Comment: You don't need to extend `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`.

Answer (score 1):

It's missing [RepositoryRestExceptionHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RepositoryRestExceptionHandler.html). Would be something like this:

Like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackageClasses = RepositoryRestExceptionHandler.class)
public class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalControllerExceptionHandler.class);

    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> badRequest(HttpServletRequest req, Exception exception) {
        log.info("++++ GLOBAL EXCEPTION HANDLING ++++");
        return null;
    }
}
```